# Mysql Create Table with substr as new column

Tags: mysql, substring, substr

I am new here.
I searched my Problem but didn´t find anything helpfull.
If there is already an answer to my Problem please link it.

I am new to Databases so maybe it will be easy.

SO anyway, here is my Problem.

I want to create a table with a column that goes like `ABCD12345`;
And make another column with a substr out of this.

My attempt looks like this

1. CREATE TABLE CLUSTERIP (
2. CLUSTER CHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
3. CLUSTER_ID CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
4. PRIM_ADMIN_NAME CHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
5. CL_PACKAGE CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
6. `DATABASE` CHAR(3) set Substr(CL_PACKAGE,6,3));

But i get a Syntax Error.
I have only seen a Substr used in Select.

So is it possible?
Is there another Way to get my 3 letters in an extra column?

Thank you,

Shagon

Comment: I don't understand, you can't make the substring on code that dinamically build the "create table " syntax?

Comment: No. I want to create a table that automatically takes 3 Chars from the CL_PACKAGE.

Comment: But .... Substr(CL_PACKAGE,6,3) = 'CKA' [CL_PACKAGE is a string!]

Comment: Means that I have to store it in a String not a Char?
Sry, but I am new to this.

Comment: I don't understand why you would create a table with a column name that is a substring of another column name. Are you sure that the substring is no referred to data (and in this case you need to manipulate a insert statement.

Comment: use test;
create table table3
(
 column1 varchar(32) not null,
 column2 varchar(16)
);
insert into table3 (column1, column2) values ('log text for column 1', substring(column1, 1, 16));

Comment: Well..I will show where where i got the Idea from.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "DB2DBA  "."CLUSTERIP"  (
    "CLUSTER" CHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
    "CLUSTER_ID" CHAR(9) NOT NULL , 
    "PRIM_ADMIN_NAME" CHAR(15) NOT NULL , 
    "PRIM_SYSTEM_ID" CHAR(12) NOT NULL , 
    "SEC_ADMIN_NAME" CHAR(15) NOT NULL , 
    "SEC_SYSTEM_ID" CHAR(12) NOT NULL , 
    "CL_PACKAGE" CHAR(10) NOT NULL , 
    "CL_PACK_ID" CHAR(9) NOT NULL , 
    "VIRTUELL_IP" CHAR(15) NOT NULL , 
    "ACT" CHAR(1) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 'N' , 
    "DATABASE" CHAR(3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(SUBSTR(CL_PACKAGE,6,3))) )   
   IN "DATEN1" ;

Comment: This is an export from the Original DB2 Database maybe it helps.

But manipulating the Insert should work.
I will ask my colleague if this works.

Comment: Ok, now is cleary. The value of column "DATABASE" is a substring of value of CL_PACKAGE column! I don't know if mysql support this, but i thing that a you may replicate this function with a trigger on this table

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help.
I will try to get it running with my coulleague tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`use test;
create table table3
(
    column1 varchar(32) not null,
    column2 varchar(16)
);
CREATE TRIGGER substring_ins BEFORE INSERT ON table3
    FOR EACH ROW
            set NEW.column2 = substring(new.column1, 1, 16);
CREATE TRIGGER substring_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON table3
    FOR EACH ROW
            set NEW.column2 = substring(new.column1, 1, 16);
insert into table3 (column1) values ('log text for column 1');
select * from table3;`